# Delete XML Node if empty?

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to figure out how to delete a bunch of nodes if they are empty. I have tried this but with no luck:

```
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $xml->formatOutput = true;
    $xml->loadXML('<library>
      <invites>
        <invite>
          <username>0</username>
          <userid>0</userid>
        </invite>
      </invites>
      <invites/>
      <invites/>
      <invites/>
      <invites/>
      <invites/>
      <invites/>
    </library>');

    echo "<xmp>OLD \n". $xml->saveXML() ."</xmp>";

    $opNodes = $xml->getElementsByTagName('invites');
    foreach($opNodes as $node) {
        $innerHtml = trim($node->nodeValue);
        if(empty($innerHtml)){
            $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
        }
    }

    echo "<xmp>NEW \n". $xml->saveXML() ."</xmp>";
```

This only removes some of the , Why?... Please help and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: i wrote similar solution for you last time.... why dont use the same solution

Comment: I have tried that, but that solution worked if an child to an Node where empty. I can't get it to work if a Node is empty. Believe me. I tried but with no luck. The other solutions works perfect for the other question.

Comment: dont just copy and paste the solution... you need to analyze code and see whats happening in there... otherwise you will never learn anything... i am not writing solution for you this time.. its so easy to modify that code and make it work in this scenario

Comment: It's ok... I'm not trying just to make you write a solution... I have tried analyzing your code and what I can get is this ( See my Edit Post ) I think taht I have to go one Node down?

Comment: If I do this: $opNodes = $xml->getElementsByTagName('invites');
foreach($opNodes as $node) {
    $innerHtml = trim($node->nodeValue);
    if(empty($innerHtml)){
  $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
} It only removes some of them? Why?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like modifying the DOM will affect the contents of your DOMNodeList (`$opNodes`) and cause some issues when iterating.  To resolve, save the nodes you want to remove in a separate list, then remove them all at once:

```
$opNodes = $xml->getElementsByTagName('invites');
$remove = array();

foreach ($opNodes as $node) {
    if (!$node->hasChildNodes()) {
        $remove[] = $node;
    }
}

foreach ($remove as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
```

Comment: Actually. It does the same as above. It removes half of the empty invites? (See my edited question)

Comment: Well, logically thinking... IF your conditional fails to remove the node then that means the length of the child node does not equal "0". Why not append an "else" conditional and evaluate each child node attribute?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I had an incomplete though and hit enter by accident which posted my reply. Let me take a second and try to come up with an example.